# Component FormFile browse at the folder level

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

I want a JSP web page that allows the user to select a folder as input,
not files. If I use , I couldn't select a folder as
input, I can only select a single file as input. In my case, are there
any solutions to my problem?

Comment: with FormFile you can select file but i want to select a folder not a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the struts docs;

> `FormFile` represents a file that has
>   been uploaded by a client.

What you are asking doesn't make sense. You can't upload a directory, only a file.

Comment: I do not want to upload a complete file, just select the name of a folder from a component as the fact FormFile

Comment: there exists a component of type FormFolder?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this. Most browsers won't let you select a directory with the form input of type file. Tested on IE8, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.